# Testing custom component with property of type @ViewChildren

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, karma-jasmine

How to test **ClientsComponent** using Karma that has a property of type `@ViewChildren` for a custom component, which also has a property of type @ViewChildren.

AppPaginatorComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-paginator',
  templateUrl: './paginatore.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./paginator.component.scss'],
})
export class AppPaginatorComponent {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  // …
}
```

ClientsComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-clients',
  templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients.component.scss'],
})
export class ClientsComponent {
  @ViewChild(AppPaginatorComponent) appPaginator: AppPaginatorComponent;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  // …

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.appPaginator.paginator.page)
     .subscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with ViewChild ? Don’t really get what do you want to test ? The merge function in ngAfterViewInit ?